# Python json file modifying

Tags: python, json

I have a problem.Every timei do this it will just replace the last users wallet.

```
data = {}
usern = ctx.message.author
usern = str(usern)
data[usern] = []
data[usern].append({
    "money": 0
})
```

Got and answer for it:
with open('config.json', 'r') as infile:
            data = json.load(infile) # load from existing

```
        data1 = data
        usern = ctx.message.author
        usern = str(usern)
        data1[usern] = []
        data1[usern].append({
            "money": 0
        })
else:  # no file, start from scratch
    data = {}
    data = {}
    usern = ctx.message.author
    usern = str(usern)
    data[usern] = []
    data[usern].append({
    "money": 0
    })

with open('config.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Comment: you need to first read the existing json, add new data, dump to json file again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the file exists & load the existing json structure from it. Change the beginning part of your program to this:

```
from os.path import isfile

if isfile('config.json'):  # check if file exists
    with open('config.json', 'r') as infile:
        data = json.load(infile) # load from existing
else:  # no file, start from scratch
    data = {}
```

Comment: But i need to have it for multiple users

Comment: The data file is still the same for all users, right? Then it should work